# Having trouble installing Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to install Swift on my Windows 11 so I can use it in visual studio code, but I keep getting the same error message over and over. The message provided in the OUTPUT is "'swift' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.".
I have tried to reinstall swift and extensions but I still can't make sense of it.
Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the directory with the swift executable in your `PATH` environment variable?